# Can Automator download many generated PDFs from a web page?

Tags: safari, automator, pdf

I've never used Automator.

Is it capable of "clicking" every link on a web age, clicking the download icon on the PDF that appears in a new tab, then closing that tab?  And also to go to the next page (because there are only twenty per page of generated output)?

These PDFs contain data on our daily hospitality registrations.  I need to pull previous years to generate some statistics, and there are probably around 200 PDFs per year.

For more detail, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50513038/how-to-automate-download-of-generated-pdfsthere are

Comment: Short answer: probably yes, but probably requires full Applescript not just an Automator action. Depends on how the links are embedded on the web page as to how easy it will be to link to them. Maybe easier to parse the web page and pull links directly to d/l the file instead of "actually" clicking.

Comment: I've left an answer on your Stack Overflow question for doing it in JavaScript. If you really want it in Automator, I can write an answer here for wrapping the JavaScript execution in an Automator workflow?

Comment: I think this should be deleted. Just ask for an Automator answer on the SO site.

Comment: Automator not mandatory.  Just fishing around for ANY way to get these things downloaded without neglecting a day's worth of other duties.  :-) Perhaps Josh is right: Since the other Q is looking for any method, that would include automator.